# SharePoint permissions issue

Tags: sharepoint-2010, permissions

I am a little confused in my about permissions, in my dev environment I have a setup the following permission groups:

- GroupOwners (Full controls).
- GroupMembers (Contribute, Approve).
- GroupVisitors (Read).

I have the following site collections:

SampleBlog/

With the following sites: SampleBlog/News/Contacts/Marketing/Finance/Property

I want to give design permissions to three users only for the following sites:

- User1 has design permissions only for SampleBlog/Contacts.
- User2 has design permissions only for SampleBlog.Marketing.
- User3 has design permissions only for SampleBlog/Finance.

The above users should be visitors for the rest of the sites.

How do I achieve this. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to remove permissions inheritance on site :
SampleBlog/Contacts
SampleBlog/Marketing
SampleBlog/Finance

then set permissions on each site like :

Site SampleBlog/Contacts
design permissions for User1
Visitor User2,User3

Site SampleBlog/Marketing
design permissions for User2
Visitor User1,User3

Site SampleBlog/Finance
design permissions for User3
Visitor User1,User2

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the advice, yep that is the approach I ended up taking.